# how to sort entire files

Tags: python, python-3.3

```
f.sort
```

This function does not seem to work

Comment: possible duplicate of [sorting content of a text file in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002392/sorting-content-of-a-text-file-in-python)

Comment: Because file `f` does not have a sort method.

Comment: why do you `f=open("classa.txt", "a")`?

Answer (score 2):

You should sort the array and not the file. Arrays can be sorted using the `sorted` function:

```
a = sorted([5, 2, 3, 1, 4])
print a
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You can find out more about this in the [docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).

In order to sort the data in the way that you request (keeping name and score together), it would be best to create a temporary tuple of name and scores and then sort that. You need to provide a custom sort key to select the average:

```
data = [
    (name, score_1, score_2, score_average),
    ....
]
data.sort(key=lambda datum: datum[3])

with open("classa.txt", "w") as f:
    for entry in data:
        f.writelines(entry)
```

If you need this to work with an existing file then you need to read the data back in in blocks:

```
with open("classa.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

data = []
while lines:
    name, score_1, score_2, avg, *lines = lines
    data.append((name, score_1, score_2, avg))
```

This code requires python 3.

Comment: Sorted is not in-place ...

Comment: You are right I was thinking of `a.sort()`