# sorting a file of list created by python with write

Tags: sorting, python-3.x

I have a file created by python3 using:

```
   of.write("{:<6f} {:<10f} {:<18f} {:<10f}\n"
                     .format((betah), test, (torque*13605.698066), (mom)))
```

The output file looks like:

```
$cat pout 
15.0     47.13    0.0594315908872    0.933333333334
25.0     29.07    0.143582198404     0.96      
20.0     35.95    0.220373446813     0.95      
5.0     124.12    0.230837577743     0.800090803982
4.0     146.71    0.239706979471     0.750671150402
0.5     263.24    0.239785533064     0.163953413739
1.0     250.20    0.240498520899     0.313035285499
```

Now, I want to sort the list.

The expected output of sorting will be:

```
25.0     29.07    0.143582198404     0.96      
20.0     35.95    0.220373446813     0.95   
15.0     47.13    0.0594315908872    0.933333333334
5.0     124.12    0.230837577743     0.800090803982
4.0     146.71    0.239706979471     0.750671150402
1.0     250.20    0.240498520899     0.313035285499
0.5     263.24    0.239785533064     0.163953413739
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002392/sorting-content-of-a-text-file-in-python) and tuples example in [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) but they are yielding the output as

```
['0.500000 263.240000 0.239786           0.163953  \n',  '15.000000 47.130000  0.059432           0.933333  \n', '1.000000 250.200000 0.240499           0.313035  \n',  '25.000000 29.070000  0.143582           0.960000  \n', '20.000000 35.950000  0.220373           0.950000  \n',  '4.000000 146.710000 0.239707           0.750671  \n',  '5.000000 124.120000 0.230838           0.800091  \n']
```

**Please**, don't try to match the numbers of input and output, because both of them are truncated for brevity.

As an example for my own try for the sorting with help from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002392/sorting-content-of-a-text-file-in-python) is like:

```
f = open("tmp", "r")
lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]
print(lines)
f.close()
```

Kindly help me sorting the file properly.

Comment: `help(sorted)` and `import operator; help(operator.itemgetter)` would be good places to start.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've found is that the strings are sorted alphabetically instead of numerically. What you need to do is convert each item from a string to a float, sort the list of floats, and then output as a string again.

I've recreated your file here, so you can see that I'm reading directly from a file.

```
pout = [
"15.0     47.13    0.0594315908872    0.933333333334",
"25.0     29.07    0.143582198404     0.96          ",
"20.0     35.95    0.220373446813     0.95          ",
"5.0     124.12    0.230837577743     0.800090803982",
"4.0     146.71    0.239706979471     0.750671150402",
"0.5     263.24    0.239785533064     0.163953413739",
"1.0     250.20    0.240498520899     0.313035285499"]

with open('test.txt', 'w') as thefile:
    for item in pout:
        thefile.write(str("{}\n".format(item)))

# Read in the file, stripping each line
lines = [line.strip() for line in open('test.txt')]
acc = []
# Loop through the list of lines, splitting the numbers at the whitespace
for strings in lines:
    words = strings.split()
    # Convert each item to a float
    words = [float(word) for word in words]
    acc.append(words)
# Sort the new list, reversing because you want highest numbers first
lines = sorted(acc, reverse=True)
# Save it to the file.
with open('test.txt', 'w') as thefile:
    for item in lines:
        thefile.write("{:<6} {:<10} {:<18} {:<10}\n".format(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3]))
```

Also note that I use `with open('test.txt', 'w') as thefile:` as it automatically handles all opening and closing. Much more memory-safe.